# Passing a column name as a variable to a select statement in a function in python / pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

assume I have a function:

```
def retrieve (c,y):
     df = pd.read_sql("select Year, ? from table where Year=? ",db, params=(c,y))
     return df
```

I want to be able to call the function as follows:

```
retrieve("col_name",2001)
```

When I remove the column name as a variable that I can pass along, it works fine. But I need to be able to pass the column name too. Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: What is the issue you are getting when passing the column name as variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a prepared statement, you can try formatting the query string in Python.

```
querysting = "select Year, {} from table where Year={}".format(c,y)
df = pd.read_sql(querystring,db)
```